# Show recaptcha in iOS native app from supremenewyork.com

Tags: ios, recaptcha

I have an iOS app in which supremenewyork.com website is opened in web view. Sometime website shows one click recaptha (like when do payment).

My client wants to show the same recaptcha in the native app if it’s shown on website when user returns to the app. Is it possible?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes — this is entirely possible. You'll first want to get the `data-sitekey` by inspecting the page source that contains the CAPTCHA, after which you can use this repo [this repo](https://github.com/dzt/captcha-ios) to get the initial implementation working in your iOS app (assuming by native you mean Swift).